# How are F# interface members implemented with object expressions?

Tags: f#

If I try to assign a function to an interface member in an object expression I get an compile error.

```ml
type IMyInterface =
    abstract member Add: a:int -> b:int -> int
    
module MyModule = 
    let myImplementation =
        let add (a:int) (b:int) : int = a + b
        { new IMyInterface with
            member this.Add = add }
```

> No implementation was given for 'abstract IMyInterface.Add: a: int ->
> b: int -> int'. Note that all interface members must be implemented
> and listed under an appropriate 'interface' declaration, e.g.
> 'interface ... with member ...'.   At least one override did not
> correctly implement its corresponding abstract member

I can make it work by supplying the parameters

```ml
module MyModule = 
    let myImplementation =
        let add (a:int) (b:int) : int = a + b
        { new IMyInterface with
            member this.Add a b = add a b}
```

However, if I create a named type signature for the function I can just assign the function and it works fine.

```ml
type Add = int -> int -> int

type IMyInterface2 =
    abstract member Add: Add
    
module MyModule2 =
    let myImplementation2 =
        let add (a:int) (b:int) : int = a + b
        { new IMyInterface2 with
            member this.Add = add }
```

It appears that
`abstract member Add: a:int -> b:int -> int`
and
`abstract member Add: Add`
are the same thing.

I don't understand the difference. Why is the function type needed to be able to assign the function directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a case where decompiling to C# is helpful. The F# compiler has silently uncurried `IMyInterface`, so it looks like this in C#:

```cs
// C#
interface IMyInterface
{
    int Add(int a, int b);
}
```

This helps explain why your attempt to implement `IMyInteface` with a curried function didn't work.

However, the compiler can't uncurry `IMyInterface2`, so it looks like this in C#:

```cs
// C#
interface IMyInterface2
{
    FSharpFunc<int, FSharpFunc<int, int>> Add { get; }
}
```

In general, I would discourage attempts to define interfaces with curried signatures, because it often leads to this sort of confusion. I suggest the following instead:

```ml
type IMyInterface3 =
    abstract member Add: a:int * b:int -> int
    
module MyModule3 = 
    let myImplementation3 =
        let add (a:int) (b:int) : int = a + b
        { new IMyInterface3 with
            member this.Add(a, b) = add a b }
```

Comment: Fascinating. I've stumbled into a dark F# alley :-).

Comment: I had been using F# records to group some related functions. I read in the F# guide that interfaces are recommended over records of functions. It will be kind of downgrade to switch to uncurried parameters on these. I think I'll stick with the type signatures to make it work. The added confusion is definitely a regrettable downside.

Comment: It's a matter of taste, but I think a record of functions is more idiomatic in F#. I stay away from interfaces unless I have to interop with C#.